# How to translate group mongo in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a document from mongo as follows:

```
{"data":[{
    "results":{
        "user_id":"1234",
        "user_type": "A",
        "user_name": "Brian Johanson",
        "city":"Winnipeg",
        "count":{
            "id": 2,
            "file_id": 14
        }
    }
}]
}
```

I have a version of this working in the mongo shell, but can't get the same to function in Python, which is where the problem is.

I am very new to mongo, but essentially I am trying to do the mongo equivalent of:

```
SELECT user_id, max(user_type), max(user_name), MAX(city), count(id), count(file_id), count(*) from userlogs where event_time<1948306176 and event_time> 1048306176 group by user_id
```

I poked around at doing this manually in mongo using group and aggregate for a while, but ended up using an online translator to generate this:

```
db.user.group({
"key": {
    "user_id": true
},
"initial": {
    "countid": 0,
    "countfile_id": 0,
    "countstar": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    prev.maximumvalueuser_type = isNaN(prev.maximumvalueuser_type) ? obj.user_type : Math.max(prev.maximumvalueuser_type, obj.user_type);
    prev.maximumvalueuser_name = isNaN(prev.maximumvalueuser_name) ? obj.user_name : Math.max(prev.maximumvalueuser_name, obj.user_name);
    prev.maximumvaluecity = isNaN(prev.maximumvaluecity) ? obj.city : Math.max(prev.maximumvaluecity, obj.city);
    if (obj.id != null) if (obj.id instanceof Array) prev.countid += obj.id.length;
    else prev.countid++;
    if (obj.file_id != null) if (obj.file_id instanceof Array) prev.countfile_id += obj.file_id.length;
    else prev.countfile_id++;
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
    else prev.countstar++;
},
"cond": {
    "event_time": {
        "$lt": 1948306176,
        "$gt": 1048306176
    }
}
```

});

Which appears to produce the above document in the mongo shell, however I need this to work in Python.

I tried a couple variants of this:

```
group_key = """{
    "user_id": true
}"""
group_initial = """{
    "countid": 0,
    "countfile_id": 0,
    "countstar": 0
}"""
group_reduce = """function(obj, prev) {
    prev.maximumvalueuser_type = isNaN(prev.maximumvalueuser_type) ? obj.user_type : Math.max(prev.maximumvalueuser_type, obj.user_type);
    prev.maximumvalueuser_name = isNaN(prev.maximumvalueuser_name) ? obj.user_name : Math.max(prev.maximumvalueuser_name, obj.user_name);
    prev.maximumvaluecity = isNaN(prev.maximumvaluecity) ? obj.city : Math.max(prev.maximumvaluecity, obj.city);
    if (obj.id != null) if (obj.id instanceof Array) prev.countid += obj.id.length;
    else prev.countid++;
    if (obj.file_id != null) if (obj.file_id instanceof Array) prev.countfile_id += obj.file_id.length;
    else prev.countfile_id++;
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
    else prev.countstar++;
}"""
group_cond = """{
    "event_time": {
        "$lt": 1948306176,
        "$gt": 1048306176
    }
}"""
all_events = db["userlogs"].group(key=group_key, initial=group_initial, reduce=group_reduce, condition=group_cond)
```

However, this yields "failed: initial has to be an object."

How do I produce the above document in Python?

Comment: We will not translate your sql query for you but we may be able to help if you provide sample document with the expected result.

Comment: Updated with the intended result document.

Comment: Is this the output of `db.collection.find()`? if so what is the expected result? Also please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to generate a document formatted as below using Python/mongo:

    {"data":[{
    "results":{
        "user_id":"1234",
        "user_type": "A",
        "user_name": "Brian Johanson",
        "city":"Winnipeg",
        "count":{
            "id": 2,
            "file_id": 14
        }
    }
}]
}